# regex for single space and/or apostrophe in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm having issues with my regex.Could anyone please help me on this? Requirement: String should be alphabetic and can include single apostrophe and or single space(size should be minimum of 2)

```
Valid strings:
1. 'abc
2.' abc
3.abc '
4.abc' 
5.a 'bc
6.a' bc
```

I have used the below regex.It works for scenario 2,4,6 but doesn't work for scenario 1,3,5

```
Regex:
     "(([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])| " +
    "([a-zA-Z]*\\s\\'[a-zA-Z]*)|" +
    "([a-zA-Z]*\\'\\s[a-zA-Z]*)|"+
    "[a-zA-Z]*|" +
    "[a-zA-Z]\\s|" +
    "[a-zA-Z]\\'|" + 
    "\\s[a-zA-Z]|" + 
    "\\'[a-zA-Z]|"+
    "\\s[a-zA-Z]*|"+
    "\\'[a-zA-Z]*|" +
    "[a-zA-Z]*\\s|"+
     "[a-zA-Z]*\\')"
```

Comment: case of characters are not of concern..@ctwheels..your suggestion isnt  working for me.

Comment: This expression is what i believe used in the second line of regex I shared.Since the string should have only one space and-or one apostrophe this expression you shared wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

**Note**: The link includes `\r\n` in the regex since the input is multiline

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/NOF2Mt/2)

```
^(?!(?:[^']*'){2})(?!(?:[^ ]* ){2})[a-z ']{2,}$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
 'abc
' abc
abc '
abc' 
a 'bc
a' bc
abc
' 
ab

a
a'' bc
a  bc
```

#### Output

Below are only strings that match requirements.
**Note**: The second to last string sample is `'`  (apostrophe and space), which, according to the OP's requirements, should match.

```
 'abc
' abc
abc '
abc' 
a 'bc
a' bc
abc
' 
ab
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!(?:[^']*'){2})` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't include 2 apostraphes `'`
- `(?!(?:[^ ]* ){2})` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't include 2 spaces
- `[a-z ']{2,}` Match two or more of the characters in the set
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Answer (score -1):

Based on the provided explanation there is something smaller that you can do to fit the provided email.

```
^( |'|[a-zA-Z]){2,}
```

1. First value *^* will detect if it is a starting element and not a
   substring.
2. Then we enclose in the parentheses all the possible
   values, so, you can have a space, you can have an apostrophe or you
   can have an a alphabetic string.
3. Finally, we consider than the
   elements needs to have at least 2 characters, that's done with {2,}
   If you want to limit the max length, you just need to add the number
   in the right side. eg {2,10}.

Comment: This is exactly the same as `^[a-zA-Z' ]{2,}`, which incorrectly matches the strings.

Comment: ctwheels, is not the same, there are or operators who make the difference between the expression you have pasted.

Comment: I assure you they are identical. Your regex is just **way** less efficient. When I say way less efficient, it uses more and more steps for each additional character you add to a string, whereas `^[a-zA-Z' ]{2,}` constantly only uses 4. Also, your regex allows for `' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ` to be matched, which is clearly not what the OP is looking for.